# Cannot add new item to "Performance point content" list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, performancepoint, business-intelligence

When I click on add new item the following modal dialog appears for a few seconds and disappears. When I tried from another Browser - Chrome it prompted a download but wouldnt download with the following error:

How do I get around/fix this? Thanks

Please note that I am trying all this on browsers outside the server(client machine)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a security issue with IE bloacking the dashboard designer from launching.

Here is credit to the article I found the solution in:
http://performancepointblog.com/2011/01/how-to-manually-install-performancepoint-dashboard-designer/

Answer (score 1):

Just as a note (in case the above link dies at some point in the future), link directly to the ClickOnce installer for PerformancePoint Dashboard Designer by using the link: `https://webapp/sitecollection/_layouts/ppsma/1033/designer.application`

This will install PPDD in your start menu (under SharePoint) for easier future access.

Note, that if you include the full path to your BI site collection in the url (like above), PerformancePoint will be automatically wired to use that site collection.

If you use the url without a site collection (that is, link to the root of the web application) and there is no PerformancePoint Features activated there, you will have to manually associate PPDD with the BI site collection under Orb Menu -> Options.